# Async function return type forces Promise< T | undefined> instead of Promise <T>

Tags: typescript, promise

I have some trouble understanding the return type of an async function. Here I would like to have a promise that returns only the type Promise< Glslang > and not Promise<Glslang | undefined>. Here is the code:

```
export interface Glslang {
  compileGLSL(
    glsl: string,
    type: 'vertex' | 'fragment' | 'compute'
  ): Uint32Array;
}

let glslang: Glslang | undefined = undefined;

export default async function getGlslang(): Promise<Glslang> {
  if (glslang !== undefined) return glslang;
  const glslangModule = await import(
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
    // @ts-ignore
    /* webpackIgnore: true */ "https://unpkg.com/@webgpu/glslang@0.0.15/dist/web-devel/glslang.js"
  );
  glslang = await glslangModule.default();
  return glslang;
}
```

And here is the console error:

> Type 'Glslang | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Glslang'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Glslang'.ts(2322)

This code was not written by me and can be found here https://github.com/austinEng/webgpu-samples/blob/main/src/glslang.ts  At the moment I am just trying to run the code without error and I am trying to understand async function return types.

I tried using a try catch block around the await keywords or rewriting the whole code with Promises but I cannot seem to make it work. I also know that I could simply add "| undefined" to the promise return type but I was wondering if it is possible without.

Thank you very much

Comment: Does TypeScript know the type of `glslangModule` and `glslangModule.default()`? If not, it can't do anything but to take your type definition `let glslang: Glslang | undefined`. If you're certain that the assignment didn't lead to `undefined`, you can just write `return glslang!;`

Comment: Notice that if this code was meant to guarantee that `default()` is called only once, you've got a race condition. Rewriting to `then` syntax, and caching the promise itself (`let glslangPromise: Promise<Glslang> | undefined;`) would solve that

Comment: Well I am trying to use this npm module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@webgpu/glslang  But the only way I managed to import it right was using dynamic imports as the code above. I npm installed the module so I know the type definitions. Here they are: ```declare interface Glslang {
    compileGLSLZeroCopy(glsl: string, shader_stage: ShaderStage, gen_debug: boolean, spirv_version?: SpirvVersion): ResultZeroCopy;
    compileGLSL(glsl: string, shader_type: ShaderStage, gen_debug: boolean, spirv_version?: SpirvVersion): Uint32Array;
}

export default function(): Promise<Glslang>```

Comment: When I try to import the module the usual way ```import GLModule, {Glslang} from "@webgpu/glslang/dist/web-devel/glslang"; ``` I have the Glslang type definition but I cannot work with the default import GLModule

Comment: "*When I try to import the module the usual way, I cannot work with the default import GLModule*" - why not? What's the error? If that is what you actually aim for, don't use a dynamic import for no good reason, and try to fix the real problem.

Comment: The error is the following: ./node_modules/@webgpu/glslang/dist/web-devel/glslang.js 913:26
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (913:26)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|       Module({
|         locateFile() {
>           const i = import.meta.url.lastIndexOf('/');
|           return import.meta.url.substring(0, i) + '/glslang.wasm';
|         },

Comment: Using the code ```const glslang = await GLModule() ```

Comment: I am not quite sure how to import the default in the module because of the promise in the type definition of glslang.d.ts : ```export default function(): Promise<Glslang>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off of [Bergi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66510256/async-function-return-type-forces-promise-t-undefined-instead-of-promise-t#comment117577793_66510256), the following would avoid a race condition present in the current code, and possibly resolve the type errors you're seeing as well:

```js
let glslangPromise: Promise<Glslang> | undefined;

export default function getGlslang(): Promise<Glslang> {
  if (!glslangPromise) {
    glslangPromise = import(
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
      // @ts-ignore
      /* webpackIgnore: true */ "https://unpkg.com/@webgpu/glslang@0.0.15/dist/web-devel/glslang.js"
    ).then((glslangModule) => glslangModule.default());
  }

  return glslangPromise;
}
```

In the event that `getGlslang()` is called twice synchronously, the original code would invoke `default()` twice, while this implementation would only invoke it once. That's because the race condition is avoided by *synchronously* storing a *promise*.

Since the original code was *asynchronously* storing the *value* instead, it meant that multiple invocations of `getGlslang()` before the dynamic import was resolved would determine that the module-scoped `glslang` was still initialized to `undefined`.

---

If you don't like the `.then(...)` syntax, you can achieve the same memoization by using an immediately invoked async arrow function expression:

```js
let glslangPromise: Promise<Glslang> | undefined;

export default function getGlslang(): Promise<Glslang> {
  if (!glslangPromise) {
    glslangPromise = (async (): Promise<Glslang> => {
      const glslangModule = await import(
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
        // @ts-ignore
        /* webpackIgnore: true */ "https://unpkg.com/@webgpu/glslang@0.0.15/dist/web-devel/glslang.js"
      );

      return glslangModule.default();
    })();
  }

  return glslangPromise;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can simplify the code to always import the module. As I see you use Webpack to bundle the app, it will take care of importing and caching so you can delete ~75% of the logic - basically keep only this part:

```
getGlslang(): Promise<Glslang> {
  return await import(
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
    // @ts-ignore
    /* webpackIgnore: true */ "https://unpkg.com/@webgpu/glslang@0.0.15/dist/web-devel/glslang.js"
  );
}
```

Maybe you can check the type of `await glslangModule.default();` and install the required typing if needed (or cast it with `as Glslang`)

Comment: The purpose of the `getGlslang()` isn't to act as a cache for the module, it's to memoize the function which is the `default` export of the module. Your types don't even match with this code, the return type of `getGlslang()` in your code would be `Promise<{ default: () => Promise<Glslang> }>`.

Comment: The idea behind the code is to dynamically import the Glslang module only once when it is needed and then store it in the variable glslang. That way you do not have to load the module multiple times. That means I need to store the module in a variable somewhere, hence why there is a lot of logic code.

Comment: @chrono _"That way you do not have to load the module multiple times."_ that part of this answer is correct. Webpack already caches dynamic imports so it doesn't load the module multiple times, similar to how Node.js keeps an internal cache for `require()` calls.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thank you, that is good to know